# print full score using Garageband

Tags: garage-band

I've been using Garageband on Mac to view and print scores track by track. But is there a way to print multiple tracks together for the conductor?

Comment: I highly suggest if you are intending for your music to be in the hands of performers, conductors, ect you should use an engraving software like Finale, MuseScore, Sibelius, or Lilypond.  Garageband is not ment for this and will not create very good sheet music that can be distributed.

Comment: You can export MIDI from GarageBand and import into MuseScore.. so you don't have to recreate it from scratch.